# When would I need a Virtual Function?

Tags: function, virtual

I understand that a Virtual Function is a function that can be redefined in classes that inherit that function.

Yet, I do not understand why I would need a Virtual Function. Can someone explain me or show me cases where I would need Virtual Functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nice explanation with good example
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Answer (score 0):

Any function can be redefined in a class' inheritors. The key to virtual functions is that they are *supposed* to be overriden.

Suppose you have a polygon class (in C++):

```
class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
    virtual int area ()
      { return 0; }
};
```

Now it doesn't make sense to define the `Polygon.area` function inside the polygon class, because at this level you *don't know what the polygon is*. The existence of the virtual function enforces all inheritors to implement their own version of the function.